# Migrating email from Cpanel to Google Apps

Tags: email, g-suite, migration

I'm busy moving web hosts at the moment, from a typical Cpanel installation to a cloud based service with a custom control panel. Rather than manage my clients emails on the new host I've decided to setup a Google Apps account per domain and let google do it for me.

But does anyone know if it is at all possible to migrate archived mail from Cpanel to Google Apps? I've been searching, but found no useful info from anyone else trying the same thing.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have IMAP access to your current mail, Google provides a tool that can do the migration for you:

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=61369&query=migrate&topic=&type=

Comment: I can use IMAP, but don't have access to the mail server config as it seems google require various ports are opened. That's a shame!

Comment: Those rules they talk about on the "Prerequisites" page are only referring to allowing access to your IMAP server from google's servers. It's most likely the case that there are currently no restrictions on what IP addresses can access your current IMAP server, so that should pose no problem. No other ports other than IMAP should need to be accessible.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look into imapsync, http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/

It's rather robust, if a little daunting at first, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: sounds useful, but don't they have any binaries for download? I could only find the source code